# Selecting rows using user id in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, security

I have a table named Grades that has the grades of the students. I also have created a role named Student and a user named Bob. Student is granted Bob. I want Bob to be able to view his and only his grades. I'm not writing an application but the database schema. I'm trying to create this view

```
CREATE VIEW My_Grades AS SELECT * FROM Grades WHERE <and here is my issue>
```

My problem is that I need a way for oracle to be sure that Bob is indeed authorized to view the grades that he is asking for. So could I for example, add a column with the uids named User_Id in the table Grades and then do

```
CREATE VIEW My_Grades AS SELECT * FROM Grades WHERE User_Id = uid
```

I'm referring to the uid that is a reserved word for Oracle. I have two questions:

1. Will the above sql statement work? And by that I mean will the uid be replaced by the current user's id in our case bob?
2. Is this a logical approach security wise? And by that I mean is there a simpler/better way to do it?

Comment: In answer to your first question (the only one I am qualified to answer) yes, it will work. Just tested it in Oracle 10g.

Comment: Generally we don't create individual database accounts for each individual user anymore - instead, we get the application to set a variable (e.g. client_identifier) to an ID that can be looked up in an "application users" table.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp Yea I had a feeling that the modern approach would be something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution with the view will work, but may get out of hand as your system grows.  If you do take this approach, you may want to base it on `user` (the name) rather than `uid` (the internal id).

Oracle has a feature called "[Virtual Private Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#DBSEG98215)" which can be used to achieve what you want.

From the link above:

> Oracle Virtual Private Database (VPD) enables you to create security
>   policies to control database access at the row and column level.
>   Essentially, Oracle Virtual Private Database adds a dynamic WHERE
>   clause to a SQL statement that is issued against the table, view, or
>   synonym to which an Oracle Virtual Private Database security policy
>   was applied.

Comment: I thought that it would be better to take the user id approach because it would take less space in the Grades table. Mind explaining why use the user name?

Comment: The size of the data required to identify a user is least of your concerns unless you're planning on supporting trillions of users.